# Java Netbean sum of a column code

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I'm confused that why `jTextField`, `TOTALAMOUNT` , is showing nothing for the following code, why ?

```
public double SUM(){

    int rowcount = BILL_INFO_TABLE.getRowCount();
    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<rowcount;i++){

         sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(BILL_INFO_TABLE.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());

    }

    return sum;   
}


private void BILL_DETAILSMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
{                                          

   DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)this.BILL_DETAILS.getModel();
    int i = BILL_DETAILS.getSelectedRow();
    if(i==-1){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"SELECCION !!");
    }else{

        DATA_TABLE2();

        TOTALAMOUNT.setText(Double.toString(SUM()));
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is very unclear. jTextField is not included in this code extract.

Comment: sorry..mainly I rename 'jTextField' by 'TOTALAMOUNT'.